# How to index this join/group/order by?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-performance

I have a query that is running slowly.  I'm pretty sure that the bottleneck is a sequential scan in the plan, so I would like to build appropriate indexes and/or rearrange my query to improve upon that.

Here is my query (and [here is a fiddle with a schema and test data](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qMaHS6PBw2Qj4yEtXBe4hw/2)):

```
SELECT conversations.id, max(messages.timestamp) as latest_message FROM
    conversations JOIN messages on conversations.id = messages.cid
    WHERE conversations.userid=1
    GROUP BY conversations.id ORDER BY latest_message;
```

I have made indexes on all of the involved columns, and nested indexes on `cid` and `timestamp` in both directions, all to no avail.  The sequential scan remains:

```
 Sort  (cost=200.60..200.65 rows=20 width=12)
   Sort Key: (max(messages."timestamp"))
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=199.97..200.17 rows=20 width=12)
         Group Key: conversations.id
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=11.50..197.97 rows=400 width=12)
               Hash Cond: (messages.cid = conversations.id)
               ->  Seq Scan on messages  (cost=0.00..160.00 rows=10000 width=12)
               ->  Hash  (cost=11.25..11.25 rows=20 width=4)
                     ->  Seq Scan on conversations  (cost=0.00..11.25 rows=20 width=4)
                           Filter: (userid = 10)
```

How can I improve this query and/or what indexes can I build to fix these sequential scans?

Comment: **Pro tip** don't willy-nilly add lots of single-column indexes in attempts to speed up queries. They have their place. But many queries are better accelerated by good choices of multi-column indexes.

Answer (score 1):

For this version of the question, I would suggest:

```
SELECT c.id,
       (SELECT max(m.timestamp) 
        FROM messages m
        WHERE c.id = m.cid
       ) as latest_message
FROM conversations c
WHERE c.userid = 1
ORDER BY latest_message;
```

You want indexes on `conversations(userid, cid)` and `messages(cid, timestamp)`.

Comment: Hmmmm.  Will the subquery on messages aggregate over the entire messages table before filtering by user?

Comment: @Scott . .  It will use the index.  That should be better than aggregating in the outer query, but you can always compare the performance.